# Automatically append session information to model in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, session, sails.js, passport.js

So I need to make associations in Sails.js.  Which is pretty easy to do with something like these models using the collection attribute(s):

Article.js

```
...
  attributes: {
        creator: {
            model: 'user'
        }
  ...
```

User.js

```
...
    attributes: {
        articles: {
            collection: 'article',
            via: 'creator'
        },
    }
...
```

Then, when I create a new article, I can associate the userId in my DB to a "creator" attribute/argument and that automatically gets stored/displayed through the ORM.

However, I'd like to know how I can automatically make that association through the session being used by sails.  So that I don't have to do a lookup on the user id or (gasp) store the user id and pass that back and forth through the wires.

My small knowledge of MVC dictates that this logic belongs in the the Controller, however by default I can CRUD to my Articles with nothing inside `ArticleController.js`

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do when you create the article associated to the user? Are you just trying to associate the current user with the Article that is being created?

Comment: @brittonjb yes, exactly. The user that's current in that session is what I'd like to automatically associate a model with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a user that already has a session, they should be passing a token with their request.  This is as simple as pulling the userID out of the token (assuming it is already in the token).

You can access the token as a property of the request object.  In your case, it is likely something as simple as setting `userId = req.token.id;` inside your create method, and assign to whatever field you want.

Comment: Considering how I may want to append the user id to multiple models (as an association) should I create this logic in a controller or in a service (or something totally different)?  Could you give me an example of doing so, the Sails docs are pretty good but I'm not totally familiar with the MVC structure.